# black star symbol for geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

I'm making a study map with ggplot2, and would like to use a black star symbol like this [★](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm) to plot city locations.

Is there a way to adjust the pch argument in geom_point to plot that symbol, maybe using a unicode expression? I've been successful at plotting other unicode symbols in ggplot2 with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point(pch="\u2265", size=10)
```

When I use \u2605 instead for a black star symbol, the resulting plot just shows hollow rectangular symbols. Is there a different way to do this, or an alternative unicode for that symbol? I am using RStudio on my Mac if that makes a difference.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: I get the black star with your code (\2605), on Windows. I unknow this method, thanks!

Comment: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/11/emojis-in-ggplot-graphics.html might be of generic help

Comment: Works for me on Windows too - using \2605 as PereG suggested

Comment: I'm running Windows in Parallels and \u2605 works fine. Seems to be a Mac issue then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `geom_text()` instead of `geom_point()` and input directly a black star as the label (need to set `family` to a font that supports the character)

`ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_text(label="★", size=10, family = "HiraKakuPro-W3")`

Comment: Tried this, it plotted the star once interactively, but when I incorporated it with a more complex plot (that worked fine before) the runtime increased from a few seconds to over a minute, and it plotted garbage rather than a star.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point(shape="\u2605", size=10, fill = "black")
```

The answer here may be just to set the `shape` parameter to the unicode `\u2605`.

Using a Mac here too.